# Jquery - Resgatar o valor de uma 'td' e inserir dentro de um Text

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, css

Boa noite ,

Seguinte galera , tenho uma tabela da qual gero os dados a partir do mysql ,
queria pegar o valor da td ,e inserir dentro de um TEXT que ira aparecer dentro da TD da tabela com o valor que estava ali para que  possa ser editado e atualizado no banco, estou tentando usar JQuery para realizar tal proeza mas sem sucesso.

Tentei algo assim:

```
$(function(){
   $('#ID_DA_TD').click(function(){
      var teste = $('#ID_DA_TD').text();
      $('#ID_DA_TD').html('<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="upgrade" style="width:150px;">');
      $('#upgrade').val(teste);
   });
});
```

Desculpa minha ignorância mas sou iniciante, vlw.

Comment: Coloca também o código do html da tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa pegar pelo `id` (senão você vai ter que criar vários eventos para cada `id`). Basta pegar pelo click na `td`. É preciso também criar `ids` dinâmicas para os novos `inputs`, senão irá existir vários `inputs` com o mesmo `id`, o que é errado. Você pode criar `ids` diferentes usando o index da `td`.

Use também o método `.trim()` para limpar as extremidades do texto.

### Edit

Incluí um botão auxiliar para retornar o estado original da `td`:

```js
$(function(){
   $('table td:not("input")').click(function(e){
      if($(this).find("input").length == 0){
         var idx = $('table td').index(this);
         $(this)
         .html('<input data-original="'+$(this).text().trim()+'" value="'+$(this).text().trim()+'" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="upgrade'+idx+'" style="width:150px;"><button>X</button>')
         .find('input').focus();
      }else if(e.target.tagName == "BUTTON"){
         $(this).html($(this).find("input").data("original"));
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="td1">
         texto 1
      </td>
      <td id="td2">
         texto 2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show , vlw brother

Comment: E para clicar e voltar ao estado original a td ?

Comment: Onde seria o click?

Comment: Na mesma td , por exemplo clicar novamente e sumir o input text , e ficar o valor novamente

Comment: Bom dia , funcionou, porém se eu clico em algum lugar da TD fora do text ele pega o value do botao e insere no text e atualiza com o valor.

Comment: Outra coisa se puder me ajudar a resgatar o valor do name do input ,porque seria algo 'upgrade+index mas não consigo resgatar  o index, o name na verdade

Comment: Arrumei o lance de clicar na td. Vc tá colocando "name+index" e quer resgatar isso?

Comment: Por exemplo , ele vai gerar o name desse input com "upgrade + o index " , mas como eu posso resgatar esse valor pra poder enviar no form

Comment: Veja bem, o form irá enviar o campo normalmente com o name que tiver, não importa se é "upgrade1" ou "upgrade10"... o que vc tem que saber é **como capturar o campo depois de enviado no PHP** (se vc estiver usando PHP)... isso porque vc não vai saber qual o name foi enviado, que pode ser qualquer número no index. Não é isso?

Comment: Lá no PHP, na captura do form, vc precisa de alguma forma listar todas as variáveis enviadas pelo form, assim vc vai poder pegar o name que foi enviado, e então fazer o que deseja com ele.

Comment: meus form é gerado dentro de um foreach a partir de um array o que gera vários inputs com o name = upgrade+idx+ , se eu for receber eles com o POST $_POST['upgrade'] se não estiver o name correto ficará null

Comment: Posso fazer assim então , foreach( $POST as key => value){ $value['name']?

Comment: Envie esses campos como array. Por exemplo, coloque o name assim <input name="upgrade[]" /> e no PHP ele será uma array que vc pode correr e pegar os valores.

Comment: No PHP vc irá pegar com $_POST['upgrade'] que será uma array com todos os valores dos campos

Comment: então não preciso usar mais o idx ?

Comment: Neste caso o idx fica desnecessário. Eu usei o idx apenas para gerar id diferente para cada input.

Comment: blz vou tentar aqui , muito obrigado